# Laradock Port ranges don't match in length Errors

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

I'm starting to use Docker with Laradock.When I run this command

```
docker-compose up -d apache2 mysql
```

I'm getting this errors:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.proxy.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]'
services.proxy2.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]'
services.memcached.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.beanstalkd.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.mssql.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.rabbitmq.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.rabbitmq.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.netdata.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.beanstalkd-console.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.zookeeper.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.gitlab.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.workspace.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.maildev.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.mongo.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
```

I'm using Mac and already restart docker.What I need to fix?

Comment: The error message indicates that there is an error in your `docker-compose.yml` file. You need to add the contents of this file to your question if we are to help you :)

Comment: docker-compose.yml total coding lines1418 and auto generated by Laradock.Thanks :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just for info for whoever is getting this error using laradock, it happens because the .env file is missing, create a .env file with this content on your docker (laradock) folder:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laradock/laradock/master/env-example

Comment: I had this issue today. I already had a .env file, but for some reason it wasn't being read. 'cp env-example .env' fixed it.